# Google Tag Manager - Variable appears undefined

Tags: function, variables, dom, return, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to write a value from the DOM into a Google Tag Manager Variable. I'm using the standart variable "Click Element". The Element i want to track is an HTML element with some attributes. If i let the variable be shown in the console it works like a charm. If i return the same value, google manager shows "undefined" in the debug mode.

What could be the mistake?

```
function() {
    var e = {{Click Element}};
    var namestr = e.dataset.src.split("/")[10];
    console.log(namestr); //works
 return namestr;  //doesnt work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason was simple. I don't know why, but the "click element" variable of the Google Tag Manager is NOT filled by the element the user clicked. It uses the parent element above. So the answer is:

```
var namestr = e.children[0].src.split("/")[10];
```